# sublime text throwing python permission while running node js code

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am getting below error while running node js file containing single line console.log("test line"); code.

Mac OS

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./python3.3/threading.py",
>   line 901, in _bootstrap_inner   File "Nodejs in
>   /Users/Vj/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed
>   Packages/Nodejs.sublime-package", line 40, in run   File "Nodejs in
>   /Users/Vj/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed
>   Packages/Nodejs.sublime-package", line 28, in run   File
>   "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 819, in **init**   File
>   "./python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1448, in _execute_child
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Thanx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime has no right for executing node.

In more detail: Sublime is done in python, that's why you see the python stack trace. `subprocess.execute_child` is pythons function how to start programs. And this failing means that python doesn't have the right to start node.

### Reproducing the issue

- verify that sublime is using your user to run (e.g. using the OSX `activity monitor`)
- open a shell and type `node /path/to/your/node/program.js`. You should run into the same issue as sublime does (sublime is using the same `$PATH` setting as your console to start executables)

### Fixing the issue

Choose one of these:

- fix the rights for the node executable for your user
- you may fix your `$PATH` variable to point it to the node executable for which you have enough rights
- you may hardwire the path to your node executable in Preferences -> Package Settings -> Nodejs -> Settings User

For the last part you copy-paste the settings from Settings from `Settings - Default` and change the relevant bits. That's what I currently have in `Settings - Default`:

```
{
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": false,
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": false,
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": false,

  "expert_mode": false,

  "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just installed [nodejs plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Nodejs)

I'm running Sublime Text Build 3126,
OS X 10.12.2

Nodejs version installed 6.9.2.

Working well.